# Как показать N последних тегов (меток)?

Tags: git, git-tag

У меня есть репозиторий, в котором достаточно много меток. Я хотел бы увидеть только несколько последних. Если я использую обычную команду, то получаю полный список меток, и он отсортирован в порядке, обратном тому, который мне нужен.

```
git tag

v1.0.0
v1.1.0
v2.0.0
v2.0.0RC1
v2.0.0RC2
v2.0.0RC3
v2.0.1
v2.1.0
v2.1.0RC1
v2.1.0RC2
```

Что я хочу:

```
git magic

v2.1.0RC2
v2.1.0RC1
v2.1.0
```

Как я могу получить список из N последних меток, отсортированных в нужном мне порядке?

---

<sub>Для будущей пометки связанных вопросов на разных языках: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805098/how-to-display-last-n-tags-in-git</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## С помощью [`git tag --sort`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-tag/) (Git v 2.0.0+ )

Обратите внимание, я использую знак минуса `-`, чтобы инвертировать порядок сортировки (по умолчанию используется от более старых к новым).

#### UNIX, Linux, OS X: [утилита `head`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28Unix%29)

```
git tag --sort=-version:refname | head -n <number>
```

#### Windows, UNIX-way

1. Установите [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
2. Используйте ответ для UNIX

#### Windows, [команда `Select`](https://serverfault.com/questions/490841/how-to-display-the-first-n-lines-of-a-command-output-in-windows-the-equivalent)

```
git tag --sort=-version:refname | Select -First <number>
```

## С помощью [`git describe`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)

```
git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=<number>)
```

<sub>([Это перевод собственного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811825/2790048). [Вариант с describe предложен @hsirah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811684/2790048).)</sub>